# Are the following 5 tenets of historical record examination considered complete today?

Tags: ancient-history, bible, historical-criticism

In his lectures recorded in the book *Historical Evidences of the Truth of the Scripture Records*, p. 39, (https://archive.org/details/historicaleviden1862rawl), George Rawlinson outlines 4 laws or degrees of credibility when examining a historical record. I have quoted them below.

Would these assertions be considered accurate today? Is there anything credible historians today would add or remove from these four statements?

> 1. When the record which we possess of an event is the writing of a contemporary, supposing that he is a credible witness, and had means
>      of observing the fact to which he testifies, the fact is to be
>      accepted, as possessing the first or highest degree of historical
>      credibility. Such evidence is on a par with that of witnesses in a
>      court of justice, with the drawback, on the one hand, that the man who
>      gives it is not sworn to speak the truth, and with the advantage, on
>      the other, that he is less likely than the legal witness to have a
>      personal interest in the matter concerning which he testifies.
> 2. When the event recorded is one which the writer may be reasonably supposed to have obtained directly from those who witnessed it, we
>      should accept it as probably true, unless it be in itself very
>      improbable. Such evidence possesses the second degree of historical
>      credibility.
> 3. When the event recorded is removed considerably from the age of the recorder of it, and there is no reason to believe that he obtained it
>      from a contemporary writing, but the probable source of his
>      information was oral tradition; still, if the event be one of great
>      importance, and of public notoriety, if it affected the national life,
>      or prosperity, —especially if it be of a nature to have been at once
>      commemorated by the establishment of any rite or practice, —then it
>      has a claim to belief as probably true, at least in its general
>      outline.  This, however, is the third, and a comparatively low, degree
>      of historical credibility.
> 4. When the traditions of one race, which, if unsupported, would have had but small claim to attention, and none to belief, are corroborated
>      by the traditions of another, especially if a distant or hostile race,
>      the event which has this double testimony obtains thereby a high
>      amount of probability, and, if not very unlikely in itself, thoroughly
>      deserves acceptance. The degree of historical credibility in this case
>      is not exactly commensurable with that in the others, since a new and
>      distinct ground of likelihood comes into play. It may be as strong as
>      the highest, and it may be almost as weak as the lowest, though this
>      is not often the case in fact. In a general way we may say that the
>      weight of this kind of evidence exceeds that which has been called the
>      third degree of historical probability, and nearly approaches to the
>      second.

**Edit:**

Upon further reading I see that he adds a 5th rule, on page 42, that historians go by (but that he disagrees with):

> `5.` No just perception of the true nature of history is possible, without a perception of the inviolability of the chain of finite
>   causes, and of the impossibility of miracles.

Comment: "that he is less likely than the legal witness to have a personal interest in the matter concerning which he testifies." if anything he is more likely to have an interest, as he/she bothered to write it down while a court witness has to testify.

Comment: also why does he disagree with the fifth?

Comment: He disagrees with the 5th because he believes in God.

Comment: I suppose the reason he/she bothered to write it down likely could be just the fact that he/she is a historian. (Is there a fallacy in my defense here?)

Comment: @NathanCain Being a historian doesn't make you an uninterested chronicler of events. It is a modern concept that a chronicler should even *be* disinterested, and a newer one that any chronicler claiming disinterest is mistaken.

Comment: @NathanCain Historians in the past where usually wealthy people who wrote down history as a hobby. Of course they took an interest. They usually even had an agenda (19th century historians for example often tried to legitimise the creation of a nation state.)

Comment: "No."  These dicta are out of date and overly simplify the problem of reading primary sources.  There's nothing about texts in context or the partiality of the documentary record.  There's no bias analysis.  The depiction of the social totality as a chain of finite causes is extraordinarily unusual for the contemporary era.

Answer (score 3):

People might still agree on these points, but with a few addenda

1. The simple fact that the witness has bothered to record an event proves that (s)he has an interest there, so the trustworthiness can be immediately questioned.
2. The [reliability](http://www.apa.org/monitor/apr06/eyewitness.aspx) of [eyewitness testimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyewitness_testimony) is, in general, dubious.

Generally speaking, [inanimate testimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy#Excavation_campaigns) beats [eyewitness testimony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad).

Comment: Point 2 needs repeating, often. It is now becoming well recognized as the *least reliable* of courtroom testimony.

Comment: Would a modern historian equate written eyewitness testimonial by an ancient historian with the low value of an eyewitness in a court case?

Comment: @NathanCain: I think this largely depends on whether the testimony is corroborated by other evidence (and, alas, also on whether the testimony agrees with the historian's personal ideological view).